# Optional additional data on ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

I have a ManyToManyField in Django, and I want to save additional information for the relation. What I am doing is

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    speakers = models.ManyToManyField(Speaker, blank=True, null=True, through='Role')

class Role(models.Model):
    speaker = models.ForeignKey(Speaker)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

As per [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany), this prevents Django from doing some automatic stuff. What is particularly annoying is that it makes the Speaker list not available when creating an Event in the admin.

I realize that in general Django does not know what to put in the `Role.role` field. But that is optional (`blank=True`). I would expect that

- either Django recognizes that Role has only optional fields and lets me use the many to many relation as usual (creating the fields with an empty default), or
- Django admin lets me add Speakers to a newly created event, and for each such Speaker it asks for the additional information (the value of `Role.role`).

The second possibility would be more useful and more general than the first. Still Django admin does none of the two: instead the speakers field is removed from the Event.

> Is there a way to make Django admin behave as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947843/django-how-does-manytomanyfield-with-through-appear-in-admin). Briefly, one should use `InlineModelAdmin`, as documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models). This realizes exactly the second behaviour I described.