# join two tables using another relation table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am having a problem with list_display in admin panel.

```
class Categories(models.Model):
      cat_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      cat_name = models.CharField(_('category name'), max_length=50)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.cat_name

class Stories(models.Model):
      story_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      story_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      story_desc = models.TextField()
      cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      date_of_publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

      def __unicode__(self):
           return self.story_title

class Relation(models.Model):
      tbl_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      story_id = models.ForeignKey(Stories)
      cat_id = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
```

I want to connect two tables, Stories and categories using Relation table in mysql. But i dont want any more columns in Relation table.

Also, I want to list in admin panel-

```
class StoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = (story_title, story_desc, date_of_creation, cat_name)

admin.site.register(Relation, StoryAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

and this:

[django: how does manytomanyfield with through appear in admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947843/django-how-does-manytomanyfield-with-through-appear-in-admin)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your relation using `ManyToMany` field. Also the way you are getting the `cat_name` is wrong since that attribute don't belongs to Story table. You should create a function to get all categories for one Story (i.e string joining) and then add that function to `list_display`.