# join two tables in django admin to get columns for display_list

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I am having problem with list_display/joining two table for django admin interface.

I want to have columns- **program_name** and **is_active**  from **SchPrograms** model with **parameter_name, parameter_description** from **VisVisitParameters** model in django admin. I am able to have those columns which i am using with return in each of these models. I tried to take help from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792209/join-two-tables-using-another-relation-table-in-django) that already has been asked. But still i could not able to figured this out.

```
class SchPrograms(models.Model):
  program_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  program_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
  creation_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  is_active = models.IntegerField()

  class Meta:
      managed = True
      db_table = 'sch_programs'
      app_label = 'polls'

  def __str__(self):
      return self.program_name

class VisVisitParameters(models.Model):
   vparameter_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   parameter_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
   parameter_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   is_active = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'vis_visit_parameters'

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.vparameter_id)
       app_label = 'polls'


class VisVisitParameterMappings(models.Model):
    vp_map_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vparameter =  models.ForeignKey(VisVisitParameters,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    program = models.ForeignKey(SchPrograms,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    display_order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'vis_visit_parameter_mappings'
       app_label = 'polls'

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.parameter_name)
```

**model.py**

```
class VisVisitParameterMappings_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =   ('program_name','is_active','parameter_name','parameter_description ')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the required items on the list display page you can write your custom methods, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

For example, for your field named **program_name** you can have:

```
def program_name(self, obj):
    if obj.program:
        return obj.program.program_name

program_name.short_description = 'Program name'
```

and for another model field named **parameter_name** , you may have:

```
def parameter_name(self, obj):
    if obj.vparameter:
        return obj.vparameter.parameter_name

parameter_name.short_description = 'Parameter Name'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: some reason, not getting any values for **parameter_name** it is blank. I will check it. but one follow up question. What I need to do if i need to get more than 1 columns from one model. for example I want to have column called "is_active" along with "program_name" ? it would be help if you can guide on it.

Comment: If you want other columns such as is_active, you can write method for it also. That's the way it is documented.. :)