# Django count of sizes in product

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am creating a shop backend. I have product model and each product has many to many field to sizes model. But there is a problem: how to manage count of each size for product? I just want to control how much of each size of each product I have. My models:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Размер"
        verbose_name_plural = "Размеры"
    size = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Размер")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size


class Image(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Фотография"
        verbose_name_plural = "Фотографии"
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Фотография", upload_to='product_images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name

class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Товар"
        verbose_name_plural = "Товары"
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, verbose_name="Фотографии")
    cost = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена')
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, verbose_name='Размеры')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, verbose_name='Описание')
    structure = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Материал")
    sizes_image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Сетка размеров", upload_to='product_sizes/')
```

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you aim to achieve. It looks quite "strange" to update the count of the m2m of `Product` and `Size`, normally one has a `Cart` for example that contains the count of the items.

Comment: Now I cant manage how much of each size in product and users can add 10000000 of each size in their cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store that in the intermediate model between `Product` and `Size`, by specifying a [**`through=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). For example:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product(models.Model):
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, through='ProductSize')

class ProductSize(models.Model):
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

In essence, a `ManyToManyField` is just an intermediate model with two `ForeignKey`s to the models involved. It also adds some extra functionality to query effectively with the ORM, but that's it.

You can here for example query the sizes for a `Product` that have at least one `count`:

```
myproduct.sizes.filter(productsize__count__gt=0)
```

For more information, [see the documentation on the **`through=…`** parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

In your admin, you can add this model as an `InlineModelAdmin`, as is specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948071/67579):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Product, ProductSize

class ProductSizeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductSize
    extra = 2

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProductSizeInline,)

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats really helps but how can I show this field in admin panel now? I register ProductSize in admin, but it separate and in Product adding no more size choice

Comment: @Dimabytes: you can use an `InlineModelAdmin` for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948071/67579